# How to store login credentials in localstorage of a webview using webviewcontroller.runJavaScript method in flutter

Tags: flutter, local-storage, webview-flutter

Iam implement webview_flutter package in my flutter app.Iam not able store login credentials to local storage of a webviewwidget using webviewcontroller.runJavaScript method. iam try two type of runJavaSript function one is in comment  that is attaching in code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import 'model_response.dart';

class MyPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyPageWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.data,
      required this.totalStep,
      required this.poster,
      required this.id});
  List<Data> data;
  int totalStep;
  String poster;
  String id;
  @override
  State<MyPageWidget> createState() => _MyPageWidgetState();
}

class _MyPageWidgetState extends State<MyPageWidget> {
  late WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    // SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    //     [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: (String url) {},
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url
                .startsWith('https://www.babylonjs.com/demos/gui/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
//       ..runJavaScript('''
//localStorage.setItem('token','${widget.id}')
// localStorage.setItem('user',{
//     "userData": {
//         "_id": "63d8a45c8acb9efbdce5d8ec",
//         "email": "test@gmail.com",
//         "password": "123"
//     },
//     "message": "User Login Successfully"
// })
// ''')
      ..runJavaScript('''
alert('${widget.id}')
localStorage["token"] = '${widget.id}'
localStorage["user"] = JSON.stringify({
    "userData": {
        "_id": "63d8a45c8acb9efbdce5d8ec",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "password": "123"
    },
    "message": "User Login Successfully"
})''')
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.55:3000/model'));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
          // in the middle of the parent.
          child: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      )),

      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Errors from console:  [INFO:CONSOLE(36812)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'd')", source: http://192.168.1.55:3000/static/js/bundle.js (36812)
[INFO:CONSOLE(36812)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'd')", source: http://192.168.1.55:3000/static/js/bundle.js (36812)
[INFO:CONSOLE(36812)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'd')", source: http://192.168.1.55:3000/static/js/bundle.js (36812)

Iam trying to navigate the account page ,web only show login page becouse the missing of login credentials